# Mean of pure birth process with distinct birth rates when odd and when even

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation, poisson-process

> Let $\{N(t)\}_{t\geq 0}$ a pure birth process for which 
>   $$P(N(t+h)-N(t)=1\mid N(t)\ \text{is odd})=ah+o(h)$$
>   $$P(N(t+h)-N(t)=1\mid N(t)\ \text{is even})=bh+o(h)$$
>   Determine $E[N(t)]$.

I think that it's a good idea use the law of total expectation:
  $$E[N(t)]=E[N(t)|N(t) odd]P[N(t)odd]+E[N(t)|N(t) even]P[N(t)even]$$
How can I proceed to find the value of $E[N(t)]$?

Comment: Hint: Consider $$A(t)=P(N(t)\ \text{even})\qquad B(t)=P(N(t)\ \text{odd})$$ and $$C(t)=E(N(t);N(t)\ \text{even})\qquad D(t)=E(N(t);N(t)\ \text{odd})$$ then $$A'(t)=-bA(t)+aB(t)\qquad B'(t)=-aB(t)+bA(t)$$ and $$C'(t)=-bC(t)+a(C(t)+A(t))\qquad D'(t)=-aD(t)+b(D(t)+B(t))$$ Solve.

Comment: Any success following the hint in my comment?

Comment: Yes, Thaks for your answer.

Comment: "Yes" Good. What's next? Do you post an answer expanding on these hints (and correcting at least one typo in them)?