# Pure birth process with distinct birth rates when odd and even

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains, conditional-expectation, poisson-process

**Question:**
Let $N(t)$ be a pure birth process for which 
$$P(N(t+h)-N(t)=1\mid N(t)\ \text{is odd})=\alpha h+o(h)$$
$$P(N(t+h)-N(t)=1\mid N(t)\ \text{is even})=\beta h+o(h)$$
Determine $E[N(t)]$.

**What I have done:**
First of all, I know that this is a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2014823/mean-of-pure-birth-process-with-distinct-birth-rates-when-odd-and-when-even), but there was never an actual answer given to that question, and I don't really understand all of the hint that was given in the comments.

With that being said, I do understand the first part of the hint. If we let $$A(t) = P(N(t) 
\;\text{even}), \;\;\;B(t) = P(N(t) \;\text{odd})$$ then I have managed to show that $$A^{'}(t) = -\beta A(t) + \alpha B(t), \;\;\;B^{'}(t) = -\alpha B(t) + \beta A(t)$$
and then I used that together with $A(t) + B(t) = 1$ to solve and found $$A(t) = \frac{\alpha}{\alpha + \beta} + A_{0}e^{-(\alpha+\beta)t}, \;\;\;B(t) = \frac{\beta}{\alpha + \beta} + B_{0}e^{-(\alpha+\beta)t}$$
Since $N(0) = 0$, we have $A(0) = 1$ and $B(0) = 0$ so $A_0 = \frac{\beta}{\alpha+\beta}$ and $A_0 = -\frac{\beta}{\alpha+\beta}$

**Where I am stuck:**
However, the part I don't understand is if we let $$C(t) = E[N(t)|N(t) \;\text{even}], \;\;\; D(t) = E[N(t)|N(t) \;\text{odd}]$$ then the hint claims that $$C^{'}(t) = -\beta C(t) + \alpha(C(t) + A(t)), \;\;\; D^{'}(t) = -\alpha D(t) + \beta(D(t) + B(t))$$ and I cannot intuitively see why this is true nor can I find a derivation of these equations. In addition, the user who commented this hint then says in a later comment that there is a typo in these hints. I'm hoping someone can steer me in the right direction and show me how I might derive this second set of differential equations. Once I know how to derive them I know I can solve them, I just don't know how to come up with the equations in the first place. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I do not have a full solution, but am curious. I see that your $A(t)$ and $B(t)$ do not depend on time, but rather seem like steady state solutions? I used $A(t)+B(t)=1$ and Laplace transforms to find $A(t)=\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta} (1-\exp(-(\alpha+\beta) t) + A_0 \exp(-(\alpha+\beta)t)$ with $A_0$ set by initial conditions. But now I am unsure on how to continue and also have trouble interpreting either $C(t)$ or $D(t)$ in terms of $A(t)$ and $B(t)$.

Comment: @Nicouh You are right, thanks for the correction.